# How does excludedDocuments work with the DocuSign REST API?

Tags: docusignapi

I'm trying to figure out how excludedDocuments works in DocuSign REST API.  I assume you just add an array of document ids for this field and that will exclude those specified ids for that particular recipient.

For example, say I want to send an envelope containing two documents, ids 1 and 2, and one of the recipients-- Editor-- can only see document id = 1.  Do I just do this under the Editor:

```
{
    ....,
    "excludedDocuments":["2"]
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Editor will be able to see all the documents, you can not exclude documents from the Editor. A sample exclude documents JSON for Signer and CC recipients will be:

```
"recipients": {
    "signers": [
      {
        "email": "signeremail@gmail.com",
        "name": "1",
        "recipientId": "2",
        "routingOrder":1,
        "excludedDocuments":[2],
        "tabs": {
          "signHereTabs": [
            {
              "documentId": "1",
              "recipientId": "1",
              "xPosition": "300",
              "yPosition": "300",
              "pageNumber":1
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    ],
    "carbonCopies": [
      {
        "email": "ccemail@gmail.com",
        "name": "CC",
        "recipientId": "1",
        "routingOrder":1,
        "excludedDocuments":[1]
      }
    ]
  }
```

In above sample JSON, CC recipient will not be able to see documentId 1 and Signer recipient will not be able to see documentId 2. Signer automatically sees any document if any DocuSign tab associated to a Signer is linked to a signer.

Comment: Hi Amit.  Are you sure?  In the REST API, it has excludedDocuments and the description says it can be used for administrative roles as well for exclusion:  https://www.docusign.com/p/RESTAPIGuide/Content/REST%20API%20References/Recipients/Editors%20Recipient.htm

Comment: You are referring to old documentation link, instead you should check https://docs.docusign.com/esign/restapi/Envelopes/EnvelopeRecipients/create/#/definitions/editor. Per this link also there is no excludedDocuments property inside editors

Comment: Ok I guess Editor is just the only one that can't be excluded.  Thanks!